# How can i stop this async function with given specified time which includes OnTimeEvent?

Tags: c#, task

I've got a function which includes a timer and each time interval, OnTimedEvent occurred. Since the function should be async and it should have a specif time duration which will be canceled after that time. Can anyone help me how can I set the timeout for this function?

I tried to implement CancellationToken, but since OnTimedEvent occurred, I couldn't know how to implement it.

```
public static async Task GetResultOfComparison(string audioName)
{
    //Loading all .wav files into specified dictionary
    ReadAudioFromTextFile();

    //Gets the MFCC's of specified .Wav file with given "audioName"
    GetMFCCVectorOfSelectedWav(GetAudioFilePath(dictionary, audioName));
    timer.Enabled = false;

   //Start Recording
    SetupRecording();
    timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
    timer.Enabled = true;         
}

public static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    RecordAndExtractMFCCBDD();
}
```

Comment: How about creating your own class that inherits `EventArgs`?

Comment: Are you looking for cancellation? `using (var cts = new CancellationTokenSource(timeout)) {... }`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko yes the OP is, but the task get's kicked off and on the `timer.Elapsed` it calls `OnTimedEvent`, which would have *no* collection of the token... Of course the OP can pass a token, but what about the `OnTimedEvent`, that's where the user wants to cancel from my understanding; cancel the `RecordAndExtractMFCCBDD`...

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ actually I want to cancel RecordAndExtractMFCCBDD function, but  i don't know how to deal with OnTimedEvent

Comment: Nope, its just calling another method to compare two audio samples.